# Accessing Azure File Storage from WebJob using SMB protocol

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-files

I have a c# console application running as a web job in Azure PaaS. Since it is a legacy system and use local UNC path to put the generated pdf, I am exploring the ways I can do this on Azure Storage. Following this, I have created a storage account then File share and finally a directory inside file share. I can access the  directory from windows machine by entering the login credentials. so I know the storage is all set and working. Now I want to replace the UNC path in my c# code with the UNC(?) path on Azure PaaS but I am wondering if that would work and if yes then how I should handle the credentials? Since Microsoft says that File Share supports SMB 3.0 I reckon I should be able to use it just the way I use any on premises drive. I do not want to use REST api's to do the file operations as defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files) and in the video [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/videos/azurecon-2015-azure-files-storage-a-frictionless-cloud-smb-file-system-for-windows-and-linux/) because it would involve code changes which in my case would be a huge exercise. Since File share supports SMB protocol I was expecting to find examples where it is called from a web job. Can somebody point me to the right resource or guide me how I can accomplish this piece of functionality.

Comment: This question was marked to be closed by someone which I did not understand why but whats more funny is as soon as I accepted the answer and +1 vote, the vote disappeared. Anyways whoever marked it to be closed would you care to explain why you think so? I would be happy to take it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem -

From the [App Service sandbox Wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#restricted-outgoing-ports) -

> **Restricted Outgoing Ports**
>
> Regardless of address, applications cannot connect to anywhere using ports 445, 137, 138, and 139. In other words, even if connecting to a non-private IP address or the address of a virtual network, **connections to ports 445, 137, 138, and 139 are not permitted.**

That's largely SMB traffic.

Your options are limited, i would try to publish on [Cloud Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me) instead (worker role), still PaaS but with a vintage feel to it and no outbound port restrictions.

[Service Fabric with Guest Executable programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-guest-executables-introduction) could also be an option, although it's probably a little too involved for a simple console app. Pick Windows nodes for .NET Full Framework.